# Count total in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below, I want to get the count of ticket issued to each directorate.

```
      Title    No_ticket    Directorate1     Direcotorate2  Direcotorate3    Direcotorate4   Direcotorate5 
   Conference   2           Marketing            Finance
      Training  2               IT               Finance
      Training  2               IT               Marketing
```

I want to see the output as

```
 Directorate  Total ticket 
  Marketing       2
    IT            2
   Finance        2
```

How can i achieve this. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

My Script is

```
select Count(t.no_ticket),directorate1 
from #ticketbooking t
group by t.no_ticket,directorate1

union

select Count(t.no_ticket),directorate2 
from #ticketbooking t
group by t.no_ticket,directorate2
```

Which is not giving me what i want

Comment: Why is the answer always 2?  It looks like it should be 4 to me...  Please explain in English or in Pseudo-Code the way you want to process the example data to reach your example output.

Comment: It it per unique combination of Directorate1 and Directorate2?

Comment: You question as it stands is impossible to answer, since you are not clearly stating what you want to achieve.

Comment: Another comment on an answer says that `no_ticket` means `two tickets` and that they are distributed between the shown directorates.  What happens if there are 3 tickets?  1.5 tickets each?  2 to the first directorate and 1 to the second?  Or vice versa?

Comment: @Tobb look at the answers i have already received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comments to other questions you state that each directorate only ever gets one ticket, and that there are actually five directorate columns.

I'm going to ***assume*** that if there isn't a 5th directorate, the column contains a NULL.  That leads me to the `WHERE` clauses in my query below.

```
SELECT
    Directorate, COUNT(*) AS ticket_allocation
FROM
(
    SELECT directorate1 AS directorate FROM yourTable WHERE directorate1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT directorate2 AS directorate FROM yourTable WHERE directorate2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT directorate3 AS directorate FROM yourTable WHERE directorate3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT directorate4 AS directorate FROM yourTable WHERE directorate4 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT directorate5 AS directorate FROM yourTable WHERE directorate5 IS NOT NULL
)
    AS pivotted
GROUP BY
    directorate
```

Or...

```
SELECT
    pivotted.directorate, COUNT(*) AS ticket_allocation
FROM
    yourTable
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT yourTable.directorate1 WHERE yourTable.directorate1 IS NOT NULL  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.directorate2 WHERE yourTable.directorate2 IS NOT NULL  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.directorate3 WHERE yourTable.directorate3 IS NOT NULL  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.directorate4 WHERE yourTable.directorate4 IS NOT NULL  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.directorate5 WHERE yourTable.directorate5 IS NOT NULL  
)
    AS pivotted(directorate)
GROUP BY
    pivotted.directorate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using union all and subquery

```
select Directorate ,count(*) as [Total ticket]
from
(
   select Directorate1 as Directorate from tablename where Directorate1  is not null
   union all
   select Directorate2 from tablename where Directorate2  is not null
   union all
   select Directorate3 from tablename where Directorate3  is not null
   union all
   select Directorate4 from tablename where Directorate4  is not null
   union all
   select Directorate5 from tablename where Directorate5  is not null
)A group by Directorate
```

Comment: If `no_ticket` means the id if the ticket, shouldn't you count the distinct values?  If it means the number of tickets, shouldn't you sum the values?  The OP doesn't explain the business logic needed, so you've assumed it, I strongly recommend stating your assumed business logic.

Comment: @MatBailie, I didn't consider no_ticket here as it is confusing for me too I just consider unique combination of Directorate1 & Directorate2

Comment: @fa06 Perfect Boss. Thats what i wanted. Its not sum but count. When number of ticket 2 its means 1 ticket given to each. thanks bro

Comment: If it's confusing to you, you are disregarding data and posting a random sql statement that may or may not have anything to do with the desired logic.

Comment: @bisa - And what happens if there are three tickets?

Comment: @MatBailie  This column are actually a share point list , There is a form connected to it. I just gave a small example of my data structure, Now coming to your question, if there is 3 ticket the form will ask the requester to add 3rf directorate, so that will comes under directorate3, on that form it will only allow 5 tickets, which means till directorate5 column.

Comment: @biswa there are actually 5 directorate columns?  Please update your question!

Comment: @biswa - Don't demean yourself by calling me or others "boss".  You're better than that, and we're certainly not worthy of it.

Comment: @MatBailie You have more knowledge in SQL then me, Salute !

Comment: @fa06 That will give a row for the "empty" directorates *(be they an empty string or NULL)*.  You need to filter it out somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `cross apply`:

```
select v.directorate, Count(t.no_ticket) as total_tickets
from #ticketbooking t cross apply
     (values (t.directorate1), (t.directorate2)) v(directorate)
where v.directorate is not null
group by v.directorate;
```

Comment: The OP's comments *(on answers rather than the question)* now make the directorate columns nullable, and that there are 5 of them.